# What is the difference between these methods of converting an int to a string?

Tags: c#

```
string s = i.ToString();

string s = Convert.ToString(i);

string s = string.Format("{0}", i);

string s = string.Empty + i;

string s = new StringBuilder().Append(i).ToString();
```

Comment: Internally I think only `string.Format("{0}", i);` may work differently, although I am not sure on this. There is `int.ToString` implicitly occurring in the other cases.

Comment: `String.Format` will check if `i` implements `IFormattable` and call a `ToString` method with some parameters.

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve with this question?

Comment: The *obvious* answer to this question would be that one calls `Int32.ToString` directly, one does it indirectly through `Convert.ToString(Int32)`, one does it indirectly through `String.Format` (although it will call an overload of ToString), one does it through string concatenation, and one does it through StringBuilder.

Comment: This looks like a fair question to me, don't see any reason people are voting to close as too broad. While there might have been a duplicate that should have been pointed instead.

Answer (score 3):

They're just several ways of doing ultimately the same thing, the idea being that they allow you ease in whichever context you need them. They're all functionally equivalent, in your current usage. Of course, in other uses, they could be used to achieve radically different results.

```
string s = i.ToString();
```

This one is necessary because it must override `object.ToString()`, so this becomes the base for all the rest.

```
string s = Convert.ToString(i);
```

This one just calls `int.ToString()`, and they probably provide it just so that `Convert.ToString(object)` doesn't have to deal with boxing and unboxing of the `int` value.

```
string s = string.Format("{0}", i);
```

This one is a bit different, but still relies on `int.ToString()`. In its current form, it wouldn't be particularly useful and *would* be particularly inefficient, but basically `string.Format` is a quick way to format strings (obviously), and uses `object.ToString()` (or `IFormattable.ToString()` when available and useful, as it is for `int` when a formatter is present).

```
string s = string.Empty + i;
```

Again, not particularly useful in its current position, but this supports more advanced operations. `string s = "This is the number: " + i;` is a lot easier than having to call the `ToString` explicitly, so this is just a language feature--syntactic sugar, as it were.

```
string s = new StringBuilder().Append(i).ToString();
```

This one is like `string.Format`. As it stands, this is an inefficient thing to do. But if you were actually building something with a `StringBuilder`, it would be nice not to have to box and unbox your `int`.

---

It's kind of like this, what's the difference between these two?

```
string[] nums = new [] { "1", "2", "3", "4" };

for (int v = 0; v < nums.Length; v++)
    Console.WriteLine(nums[v]);
```

and

```
string[] nums = ...;

foreach (var v in nums)
    Console.WriteLine(v);
```

They're just two ways of doing essentially the same thing.